# Midnight commander sometimes very slow

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, midnight-commander

I'm using midnight commander with Cygwin 64 bit on Windows 10 64 bit.

After moving to a new machine and a clean reinstall of windows and cygwin, my midnight commander started to get very laggy from time to time. <del>Restarting helps, but this happens too often for that to be a viable solution</del> *(restarting doesn't help)*.

I have no idea what could be the reason for these hiccups. MC normally works fine: arrow presses work well, viewing and editing is instant, but one thing takes up to 10 seconds - changing directories. Searching in files has a similar lag, but only once (ie not in every `chdir` it could have done). In non-mc cygwin usage this issue doesn't happen.

The task manager doesn't show any abnormally high CPU or memory usage on any process. I have `cygserver` running, using `bash` as my shell and have no fancy `PS1` settings, my `$CYGWIN` is only `winsymlinks:native`.

Here is a `strace` log, maybe someone has an idea what did go wrong?
http://pastebin.pl/view/9b839815
(recorded with `LOCALE=C strace -q -o /tmp/mc-log mc /tmp`)

In the recorded session I have:

- started mc in `/tmp` directory
- entered `/tmp/NVIDIA Corporation` directory
- went back up (`..`)
- entered `/tmp/mc-chanibal` directory
- went back up (`..`)
- exited with F10

---

Additional timing information:

A find of all directories in my `$HOME` takes 4.6 seconds:

```
$ time find ~ -type d | wc -l
(snipped two directories without permissions)
19919

real    0m4.626s
user    0m0.796s
sys     0m3.765s
```

A `ls -al` on all of these directories took a lot of time, but the average was fairly low:

```
time (find ~ -type d | while read f; do { time ls -al $f; } \
   |& awk '$1 == "real" { printf $2 }'                      \
   | awk -Fm '{printf( "%2.4f", $1 * 60 + $2 )}';           \
   echo -e "\t$f"; done                                     \
) >/tmp/ls-time-log ;
(snipped two dirs without permissions)

real    12m21.870s
user    7m4.576s
sys     16m34.446s
```

The average time to do an `ls -al` is 0.020s, min is 0.017, max is 0.154:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { sum=0; min=9999; max=0;  minf=""; maxf=""; }     \
      $1 { sum += $1;                                           \
           if(min > $1) { min = $1; minf = $2; };               \
           if(max < $1) { max = $1; maxf = $2; } }              \
      END { print "avg: " sum/NR; print "min: " min " "         \
          minf; print "max: " max " " maxf }' </tmp/ls-time-log
avg: 0.0204292
min: 0.0170 /cygdrive/c/Users/chanibal/AppData/Roaming/OculusClient/Local
max: 0.1540 /cygdrive/c/Users/chanibal/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/drawable-hdpi
```

With the overhead of measuring time it averages 16m34s/19919 = 0.499s per call to `ls -al`, two `awk`s and a iteration of `find`. Not very good, but not four seconds.

---

Normalizing with `cygpath` doesn't take long:

```
$ time strace cygpath -aw /tmp/NVIDIA\ Corporation/ | grep normalize_posix_path
  116   11175 [main] cygpath 3524 normalize_posix_path: src /tmp/NVIDIA Corporation/
   20   11195 [main] cygpath 3524 normalize_posix_path: /tmp/NVIDIA Corporation/ = normalize_posix_path (/tmp/NVIDIA Corporation/)

real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

EDIT: Added this issue to [MC's trac](http://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/3662)

Comment: Is it a domain machine or stand alone ?

Comment: `$ grep normalize_posix_path 9b839815.strace | awk '{ if ($1 > 10000) print $0}'` shows a 4 seconds timeout entering some directories. Any unusual SID on file ACLs ? Can you compare with the time to run `ls -l` on the same directories ?

Comment: @matzeri: this is a stand alone windows installation, no network drives attached or domain controller

Comment: @matzeri: time of `ls -al` on the directory or it's contents is negligible (around real 0.021s)

Comment: @matzeri: added a lot of detailed timing in question

Comment: Nothing obvious on the timing . Can you check if `mc -u` has still the problem ? If not then the issue is on the interaction with the subshell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42165/discussion-between-matzeri-and-chanibal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and decided it's Windows 10 or faulty hardware fault, not MC. Midnight commander does trigger this issue, but it does so by using the OS in expected ways, so it's not its fault.

To be exact, the issue is that enumerating devices takes time (exactly 4 or 5 seconds in Windows powershell or 4 seconds in Cygwin). The fix in my case was to disable the DVD drive that was taking time. Details on the [Cygwin mailing list thread](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-07/msg00290.html).